# Why is my ArrayList of transactions null?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask

I am trying to query my database for the transactions table where the user_id is the user's id like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

                Cursor cursor = db.query("transactions", null, "user_id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(integers[0])}, null, null, null);

                if(cursor != null){
                    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

                        ArrayList<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

                        for(int i = 0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++){
                            Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
                            transaction.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));
                            transaction.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")));
                            transaction.setPrice(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("amount")));
                            transaction.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
                            transaction.setTransactionId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));

                            transactions.add(transaction);
                            cursor.moveToNext();
                        }

                        cursor.close();
                        db.close();
                        return transactions;


                    }
                }
```

Then, in the onPostExecute of this async task, I set the adapter like this:

```
if(transactions != null){
                itemsRecView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
                adapter.setTransactions(transactions);
                itemsRecView.setAdapter(adapter);


                Log.d("transactions", transactions + "");
            }
```

However, for some reason, it's not going into the if(transaction != null){} block, and instead the else block which just Logs that the array list was null.

Update: I am getting this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.krish.recreatemybank.Models.User.get_id()' on a null object reference at com.krish.recreatemybank.Activities.MainActivity.initTransactions(MainActivity.java:72)
```

..at the line execute.
***What may be going wrong here? Thanks.***

This is my TransactionsAdapter if needed:

```
public class TransactionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TransactionsAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

    public TransactionsAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(transactions.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(transactions.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.transactionId.setText(transactions.get(position).getTransactionId());
        holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(transactions.get(position).getPrice()));
        holder.date.setText(transactions.get(position).getDate());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return transactions.size();
    }

    public void setTransactions(ArrayList<Transaction> transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView title, description, date, price, transactionId;


        public ItemViewHolder(@NonNull @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemListTitle);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemListDescription);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemListDate);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemListPrice);
            transactionId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemListId);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample transaction in DatabaseHelper.java:

```
private void addSampleTransaction(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        utils = new Utils(context);
        User user = utils.isUserLoggedIn();

        if(user != null){
            ContentValues transactionValues = new ContentValues();
            transactionValues.put("type", "sample");
            transactionValues.put("user_id", user.get_id());
            transactionValues.put("description", "Hi TEST");
            transactionValues.put("date", "2021-05-25");
            transactionValues.put("amount", 25.00);

            db.insert("transactions", null, transactionValues);
        }

    }
```

Utils methods:

```
public void addUserToSharedPreferences(User user){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("logged_in_user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        editor.putString("user", gson.toJson(user));

        editor.apply();
    }



    public User isUserLoggedIn(){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("logged_in_user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<User>(){}.getType();

        User user = gson.fromJson(sharedPreferences.getString("user", null), type);
        return user;
    }
```

In my RegisterActivity I am querying like this and then adding them to the shared preferences:

```
@Override
        protected User doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try{
                SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                ContentValues userValues = new ContentValues();
                userValues.put("remained_amount", 0.00);
                userValues.put("first_name", first_name);
                userValues.put("last_name", last_name);
                userValues.put("email", emailString);
                userValues.put("password", passwordString);
                userValues.put("address", addressString);

                long userId = db.insert("users", null, userValues);

                Cursor cursor = db.query("users", null, "_id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(userId)}, null, null, null);

                if(cursor != null){
                    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                        User user = new User();
                        user.setRemained_amount(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("remained_amount")));
                        user.set_id(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                        user.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")));
                        user.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email")));
                        user.setPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password")));
                        user.setFirst_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("first_name")));
                        user.setLast_name(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("last_name")));

                        cursor.close();
                        db.close();
                        return user;

                    }else{
                        cursor.close();
                        db.close();
                        return null;
                    }
                }else{
                    db.close();
                    return null;
                }

            }catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User user) {
            super.onPostExecute(user);
            if(user != null){
                warning.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Utils utils = new Utils(RegisterActivity.this);
                utils.addUserToSharedPreferences(user);

                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure before "return transactions;" the array contains values?

Comment: What do you return if `if(cursor != null)` ? Even if transactions has 0 values it wouldn't be null due to `ArrayList<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Outside of if(cursor!=null){} there could be an exception which means transactions would be null

Comment: @javdromero, that's the problem, it's null when it shouldn't be. Also, I added the sample transaction

Comment: 1. I would avoid return null use `return new ArrayList<>()`  2. Write out the query in pure sql for now for testing to avoid all of the prepared statement shenanigans.

Comment: Why? Return null is fine.

Comment: It doesn't work for every scenario, but if your function says it returns something its best to return that something, null is not an ArrayList. Otherwise you will have to do null checks everywhere, ie `if(transactions != null)` when an empty ArrayList would have just produced an empty adapter, both are errors but one fails gracefully the other you have to stop from going over the edge.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Any idea what may be going wrong here though? Cant seem to find out why the array list is null

Comment: Hi, I'm getting this error Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.krish.recreatemybank.Models.User.get_id()' on a null object reference
        at com.krish.recreatemybank.Activities.MainActivity.initTransactions(MainActivity.java:72) at the line execute

Comment: You will need to post the code for  ` utils = new Utils(context) or User user = utils.isUserLoggedIn();` as that is where your getting the user and apparently it exists but is missing its id.

Comment: Hi, I have added the two important methods and also the part where I add the user to shared preferences

Comment: Although, when I instantiated the Utils class in the method(and not in onCreate()) this error went away, but my adapter still isn't working

Comment: It's still saying the transactions list is null

Comment: It seems like the cursor doesn't even go to moveToFirst(), meaning it has no elements, and the sample transaction didn't do it's job

Comment: `long userId = db.insert("users", null, userValues);` what value is userId if its -1 than the insert failed.

Comment: Hi, The user is getting added to the shared preferences though

Comment: I ran again, and I'm getting this exception again: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.krish.recreatemybank.Models.User.get_id()' on a null object reference

Comment: On the getTransactions.execute line